# How to manage large a dataset for regression?

Tags: python, memory, regression, statsmodels

my question has to do with a very large dataset I'm running a regression on in Python. I have categorical data (gender, industry, region, salary groupings, etc.) that I would like to run a regression on with statsmodels. The whole dataframe comes out to be about 83 columns in width after using pd.getdummies() on roughly 5 million lines.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from datetime import datetime as dt


#Start time
print('Start Time: ', dt.now())

#Variables
groups = ['sex', 'central_age', 'group_size', 'industry', 'region', 'salary']
base_cases = ['sex_Male', 'central_age_47.0', 'group_size_F. 100-249', 'salary_A. < 25',
              'industry_H. Manufacturing - heavy, steel etc.', 'region_C. Division 3: East North Central']
aggregates = ['death_amount_exposed', 'death_claim_amount']


#Read/ format data to transform data into categorical variables
df = pd.read_pickle(r'./Life_Mortality_Data.pkl')
df = df[df['death_amount_exposed']!=0]
df['central_age'] = df['central_age'].apply(str)
final = pd.get_dummies(df[groups]).join(df[aggregates]).astype(float)
final.drop(base_cases, axis=1, inplace=True)


#Prepare sting of variables to regress on in next step
var_columns = list(final.columns)
for i in aggregates:
    var_columns.remove(i)
variables = '+'.join('Q("' + i + '")' for i in var_columns)


#Training and testing with Poisson model
print('Regression Time: ', dt.now(), '\n')
res1 = smf.glm(formula='death_claim_amount ~'+variables, data=final, offset=np.log(final['death_amount_exposed']), family=sm.families.Poisson(sm.families.links.log())).fit()


#Print stats summary, base cases, and multiplicative factors
print(res1.summary())
print('Base Cases:')
for case in base_cases:
    print(case)
print('\nParameters:\n', np.exp(res1.params))


#This takes the result of a statsmodel results table and transforms it into a dataframe
def results_summary_to_dataframe(results):
    pvals = results.pvalues
    coeff = results.params
    std_err = results.bse
    conf_lower = results.conf_int()[0]
    conf_higher = results.conf_int()[1]

    results_df = pd.DataFrame({"pvals":pvals,
                               "coeff":coeff,
                               "std_error":std_err,
                               "conf_lower":conf_lower,
                               "conf_higher":conf_higher
                                })

    #Reordering columns
    results_df = results_df[["coeff","std_error","pvals","conf_lower","conf_higher"]]
    return results_df


#Write data to excel
results_summary_to_dataframe(res1).to_excel(r'./All_Regression_Amounts_v1.xlsx')


#End time
print('\nEnd Time: ', dt.now())
```

The problem I'm having is that I run out of memory at the point where the statsmodels regression is run. I am using the 64-bit version of Python on Windows and have 32 GB of memory which I thought would be more than enough to handle this kind of computation but am not sure if I'm not using all available memory or if something may be wrong with my code. I'm very new to this kind of analysis and handling this much data. I'd really appreciate any help on what I can do to resolve this error

Comment: Do you get the memory error in setting up the glm model or in `fit`?

Comment: Yes, it's primarily when fitting the model that I get a memory error

Comment: Instead of `.fit()`, can you try `.fit(method='lbfgs', max_start_irls=0)`? That will use a limited memory BFGS optimizer which might work better.

Comment: Oh... and instead of the whole `.get_dummies` approach, I suggest you just use [pandas categoricals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html#pandas.Categorical). The first level you define in the categorical variable will be the base for patsy. In patsy, if you just do a `formula='response ~ variable'`, patsy will handle the design matrix creation pretty quickly, including dropping the dummy column for the base level.

Answer (score 1):

When building linear models on datasets which are too large to hold in memory your best bet is to train the model with [Stochastic Gradient Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent). This fits the model iteratively by gradient descent using repeated small samples of the data rather than all the data at once.

Scikit-learn has a [SGDClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier) module which fits a linear model like this. You could take a look at that and see if it might work for you.